# Intellij doesn't display local mercurial repository view

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I have got project with local mercurial repository. There is view "changes -> local" where I can commit new changes, but there is no view "changes -> repository" where I can view list of my commits. How can I view my commits if I have only local Mercurial repository (using Intellij Idea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in latest IntelliJ (11.1.1) support for mercurial is not complete. If you wish to view your local commits - use console or Tortoise HG or other tool.

Answer (score 0):

The repository view for Mercurial is available in IntelliJ IDEA starting from version 12. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/